# How can I concatenate MERGEFIELDs and text in a word-merge statement?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to merge a letter that will have 1 to 3 items in a particular sentence. The basic works in the sentence are: "Thank you for your gift to MERGEFIELD org1 MERGEFIELD org 2 MERGEFIELD org 3". Sometimes there is one org, sometimes 2, and sometimes 3. The issue is the get the commas and the "and" correct. My algorithm/string is

org 1 (always prints)
if org 2 is null "."
else if org 3 is null "and" org2 "."
else ", " org2 "and " org3 "."

It's not that complicated a string, but the issue seems to be how to concatenate strings and MERGEFIELDs.

[merge code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjOfd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try org1 mergefield, followed by nested IF fields for org2 and org3, then full stop outside (after) IF field.
[image]